# Core Data performance issue when creating MKPolyline from set of NSManagedObject subclasses

Tags: ios, core-data, core-location, mapkit

I'm building a fitness application which tracks user's movement using Core Location framework. 
I'm saving the data using Core Data framework. Currently I have two entities; Workout and Location. Workout consists of these Location objects, which have latitude and longitude as their main attributes.

When I'm trying to create MKPolyLine from these Location objects it takes an awful lot of time on device.

```
- (void)createRouteLineAndAddOverLay
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[[self.workout.route count]];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.workout.route count]; i++) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = [[[self.workout.route objectAtIndex:i] latitude] doubleValue];
        coordinate.longitude = [[[self.workout.route objectAtIndex:i] longitude] doubleValue];
        coordinateArray[i] = coordinate;
    }

    self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:[self.workout.route count]];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
    [self setVisibleMapRect];
}
```

Could using of scalars make any performance improvement? Or should I try to filter out some of these locations points with some kind of algorithm when saving them?

Comment: please NSLog before and after the suspicious code. because i don't think it will take lots of time

Comment: How many coordinates your are tracking per kilometer

Comment: You need to get a better idea of where the slowdown is. *If* the above method is actually the problem, it could be Core Data slowing things down, or it could be the `MKPolyline` call, or it could be adding the overlay to the map view.

Comment: I NSLogged the time difference between start and end of the for-loop. It took 2.719334 seconds to complete. Route was 2.95km long and had 2100 Locations. MKPolyline call or adding the overlay to the map view took very little time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Trick here is to do the sorting on the database side.

```
- (void)createRouteLineAndAddOverLay
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Location"];
    NSSortDescriptor *fromStartToEnd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:fromStartToEnd];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"workout = %@", self.workout];
    request.predicate = predicate;
    NSArray *locations = [self.workout.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];

    int routeSize = [locations count];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[routeSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < routeSize; i++) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = [[[locations objectAtIndex:i] latitude] doubleValue];
        coordinate.longitude = [[[locations objectAtIndex:i] longitude] doubleValue];
        coordinateArray[i] = coordinate;
    }

    self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:routeSize];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
    [self setVisibleMapRect];
}
```

This method took only 0.275954 seconds when workout had 1321 locations

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestion for optimization:

First, you have `count+1` calls to `count` (>2000). Store the count in a variable.

Second, in your loop you are repeatedly retrieving the data from the workout object. Try storing the `route` array before starting the loop.

Besides, if `route` is a to-many relationship from `Workout` to `Location`, it should result in a `NSSet`, not an array. I suspect that you are using `NSOrderdSet`, which could also affect your performance. It would perhaps be better to keep track of the order with a simple integer attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately your first two suggestions didn't get any noticeable performance improvement. And yes, I'm using NSOrderedSet. So are you saying that I should save Locations in a NSSet format and then when accessing them in order I would create NSArray from it and sort them by this integer attribute?

Comment: Correct, that is how I would do it. Besides, 3 seconds with a nice informative progress view is probably acceptable in terms of usability. Still, I think this should be faster.